# Heavy PC falling on enemies

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, falling

I have a player who's playing as a Tortle (DND 5e) and weighs over 500 lbs. This combined with the ability for Tortles to hide in their shell led to some interesting crushing-related activities, and I had to homebrew rules on the fly. Two specific scenarios came up:

- From a standing position, the Tortle falls prone onto a smaller creature (eg a goblin). In this case, (the goblin only had like 6 hp) I gave the goblin a dex save against being crushed (instakill) as there's no way any regular goblin could withstand 500 lbs.
- From a ledge above a pinned enemy, the Tortle shelled up as it tipped over the edge and fell 30ft on top of the enemy. Again, I gave the enemy a dex save but this time I used the fall damage 3d6 as damage dealt and had the Tortle take half damage because they're shelled up and not impacting a hard surface directly.

Questions:

- Are there any rules for crush damage? Proven homebrew alternatives?
- Are there rules for reducing fall damage by landing on someone else? Can the fall damage be transfered?

Comment: Related on [How might the weight of a falling object affect the damage it causes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59090/how-might-the-weight-of-a-falling-object-affect-the-damage-it-causes) and [How do I adjudicate a PC jumping onto another creature from height?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116561/how-do-i-adjudicate-a-pc-jumping-onto-another-creature-from-a-height)

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate, I'm specifically looking for creature size difference effects and mass differences. A 500 lb Tortle dealing 1d6 to a 40 lb goblin off a 10 ft ledge makes no sense

Comment: I agree it may not be a duplicate because the linked question is about a jump and sword attack, while yours is just pure jumping. I"m not sure there's a big difference between the two, but can you explain how your question itself is different? I understand you think it makes no sense, but is your question fundamentally different than the one linked? If so, how?

Comment: Related: possibly better dupe: [If an object or creature is dropped on a monster, how much damage does each of them take?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/70529/52137)