# How much damage from a falling Orca?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, druid, falling

Level 10 Circle of the Moon Druid has two uses of wild shape. At level 2 a player gets "combat wild shape" so you can choose to use your bonus action to transform.

Combat starts, your first turn you bonus action wild shape into a giant eagle (80 fly speed) and fly up into the air 160 feet (dash action). Round 2, you move yourself over an unsuspecting enemy, maybe you even use your action to dash higher. Let's say at this point you are 300 feet above an enemy (and you have keen sight so you can definitely see him.) Time for bonus action wild shape into an orca (8-12k pounds).

Xanathar's says when you fall, you instantly descend 500ft. So you can easily drop down on an enemy before he can react. Besides, you are now a huge beast and hard to avoid. Max damage = 20d6 (200ft)

How would you rule on a target enemy taking damage vs. how much damage do you take?

Comment: And beside the falling orca was a bowl of petunias, thinking "Oh no. Not again".

Comment: Such a good reference.

Comment: Also highly related: [How might the weight of a falling object affect the damage it causes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59090/52137)

Comment: But where are my manners, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate of another question, because they appear to be materially the same, at least by my estimation. If you feel that your question is different enough that you don't feel it is answered by that question, edit in a justification and I or someone else here will re-open this post.

Comment: It's too bad this is a dupe. I was born for this.