# Galders Tower uses?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can Galders Tower be summoned on an enemy? Are there any restrictions in the casting/location of the summoning? If you were to keep an enemy monologing or otherwise engaged for 10 minutes, and

> conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials

10 feet above the enemy, how much damage would it deal? would they be able to get out of the way? I don't know how a creature could make a save to avoid a tower up to

> 100 square feet.

that they are in the middle of. furthermore, could you cast the spell to trap a creature inside of it? it doesn't specify that you need to put an entrance on it, nor that it specifies a type of material, only that it

> two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials

would that allow materials such as Mythril or iron?

Comment: Since this spell comes from a specific module, not a sourcebook, it would be useful to cite it.

Comment: This looks like you're asking multiple questions in one, splitting it up would help us give a focused concise answer.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I didn't want to spam the boards with 20 variations on similar questions, is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: It seems like your actual question isn't about the specifics, but more about the possibility. Are you really just wanting to know if you can use *Galder's Tower* as a combat offensive spell by dropping it on someone?  Related question on [Does weight affect damage for falling objects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59090).

Comment: @NautArch I was also curious if summoning it with someone inside would work and if you could trap them in there

Comment: @Aydens I see 3 questions. Your first batch of questions are exploring the same idea. Can it be summoned on someone. Then you say 'Furthermore', indicating question two: Can you trap someone inside it? And then you say 'Would...' that's question three: Can it be made of Mythril...etc?

Comment: You may be able to ask just two questions here: 1)Can Galder's Tower be used offensively and what would the damage be? and 2)Can you trap someone inside the summoning. I think the first is answered (maybe) by my first related link. The second question may have related questions here, but I haven't yet searched (you can as well!)

Answer (score 2):

> You conjure a two-story tower made of stone, wood, or similar suitably sturdy materials.

I think most DMs would qualify iron as too study to be "suitably similar" as wood.

As for dropping it on a creature. Nothing is specified, so it is up to DM discretion.

The DMG provides a bit of guidance for improvising damage:

> 10d10  **Crushed by compacting walls**, hit by whirling steel blades, wading through a lava stream

> 18d10  Being submerged in lava, being **hit by a crashing flying fortress**

If its avoidable you could look at Tasha's rules on falling:

> If a creature falls into the space of a second creature and neither of them is Tiny, the second creature must succeed on a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw or be impacted by the falling creature, and any damage resulting from the fall is divided evenly between them.

And for a similar example from a published adventure, Storm King's Thunder includes a portable boulder you can expand on command and drop on your foes.

> A creature can use an action to shrink the stone to the size of a 6-inch-diameter orb weighing 25 pounds, or enlarge the boulder to its normal size (15-foot diameter) and weight (12 tons). Anything the enlarged boulder falls on takes 55 (10d10) bludgeoning damage. A creature can avoid taking this damage by tumbling out of the way with a successful DC 15 Dexterity saving throw. Once the reducing or enlarging effect is used, this property can’t be used again for 24 hours.

For another comparison.. Instant Fortress magical item if deployed with helpless creatures in the way offers..

> a DC 15 Dexterity saving throw, taking 10d10 bludgeoning damage on a failed save,

I am starting to notice a pattern of arbitrarily large but not absolutely massive objects impacting you offering a DC 15 Dex save or dealing 10d10 damage. Whether save avoids half or not is up to your DM.

Comment: Considering the spell's 10-minute casting time, it would be very very difficult to accurately drop the tower on a creature.

Comment: If course, but that could be overcome with something like wish or maybe you just decided to drop it and a random creature was under it.